# Compiling Httrack on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, openssl, httrack

I'm trying to compile httrack on my MAC. ./configure is successful. But while compiling the package i'm getting following error, and not able to resolve it.

```
In file included from htscore.c:40:
In file included from ./htscore.h:81:
In file included from ./htslib.h:67:
./htsbasenet.h:76:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
      ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libhttrack_la-htscore.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Also tried this solution, but no luck
https://serverfault.com/questions/283271/how-to-get-httrack-to-work-with-ssl-on-mac-os-x-libssl-so-not-found

Openssl is located at /usr/include/openssl

Answer (score 7):

If you can live without HTTPS then

```
./configure --enable-https=no
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you don't have OpenSSL on path or Httrack does not pick it up. It also appears Httrack does not have a `configure` option to specify an OpenSSL directory.

It also appears Httrack rejects anything less than OpenSSL 1.0.1g (Heartbleed). OS X provides OpenSSL 0.9.8 by default, so you should [download](https://www.openssl.org/source/) and [install](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Mac) the latest version of OpenSSL.

Once you have an updated version of OpenSSL, export the needed paths through `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. Httrack picks up `LDLIBS` on its own.

```
$ export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/include"
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/lib"

$ ./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
...
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

$ cat ./config.log | grep -i openssl
| #define HTS_USEOPENSSL 1
| #define HTS_USEOPENSSL 1
OPENSSL_LIBS='-lcrypto -lssl'
#define HTS_USEOPENSSL 1
```

The above is from OS X 10.8.5 and [Htrack 3.48.21](https://mirror.httrack.com/historical/)

---

You can verify OpenSSL was linked with:

```
$ find . -name *.dylib
./libtest/.libs/libbaselinks.dylib
...
./src/.libs/libhtsjava.dylib
./src/.libs/libhttrack.dylib
```

And then:

```
$ otool -L ./src/.libs/libhttrack.dylib | grep -i ssl
    /usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

---

You should be able to test the build before the install with a `make check`:

```
$ make
...

$ make check
...
PASS: 00_runnable.test
PASS: 01_engine-charset.test
PASS: 01_engine-entities.test
md5 selftest succeeded
hashtable summary: size=262144 (lg2=18) used=72619 stash-size=0 pool-size=6693195 pool-capacity=8388608 pool-used=6480537 writes=6600000 (new=175000) moved=44471 stashed=4 max-stash-size=1 avg-moved=0.25412 rehash=14 pool-compact=15 pool-realloc=30 memory=14680688
all hashtable tests were successful!
PASS: 01_engine-hashtable.test
PASS: 01_engine-idna.test
PASS: 01_engine-simplify.test
online tests are disabled
skipping online unit tests
SKIP: 10_crawl-simple.test
online tests are disabled
skipping online unit tests
SKIP: 11_crawl-cookies.test
online tests are disabled
skipping online unit tests
SKIP: 11_crawl-idna.test
online tests are disabled
skipping online unit tests
SKIP: 11_crawl-international.test
online tests are disabled
skipping online unit tests
SKIP: 11_crawl-longurl.test
online tests are disabled
skipping online unit tests
SKIP: 11_crawl-parsing.test
online tests are disabled
skipping online unit tests
SKIP: 12_crawl_https.test
======================
All 6 tests passed
(7 tests were not run)
======================
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/.../httrack-3.48.21/tests'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/.../httrack-3.48.21/tests'
make[1]: Entering directory '/Users/.../httrack-3.48.21'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'check-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/.../httrack-3.48.21'
```

I don't know why the online tests were *not* performed since they are enabled by default:

```
$ ./configure --help | grep -i online
    --enable-online-unit-tests=[yes/no/auto]
                                    Enable online-unit-tests [default=yes]
```

Also see [Issue 92: 'make check' and "uname: illegal option -- o" on OS X](https://github.com/xroche/httrack/issues/92).

---

Their use of OpenSSL looks like it has room for improvement... You might consider opening `src/htslib.c`, scrolling down to line 5166:

```
// OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
openssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
if (!openssl_ctx) {
  fprintf(stderr,
          "fatal: unable to initialize TLS: SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method)\n");
  abortLog("unable to initialize TLS: SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method)");
  assertf("unable to initialize TLS" == NULL);
}
```

And changing it to something like:

```
// OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
openssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
if (!openssl_ctx) {
  fprintf(stderr, "fatal: unable to initialize TLS: SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method)\n");
  abortLog("unable to initialize TLS: SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method)");
  assertf("unable to initialize TLS" == NULL);
}

const long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
SSL_CTX_set_options(openssl_ctx, flags);

const char PREFERRED_CIPHERS[] = "HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!PSK:!SRP:!MD5:!RC4";
long res = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(openssl_ctx, PREFERRED_CIPHERS);
if (res != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "fatal: unable to initialize TLS: SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(PREFERRED_CIPHERS)\n");
  abortLog("unable to initialize TLS: SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(PREFERRED_CIPHERS)");
  assertf("unable to initialize TLS" == NULL);
}
```

There are some other things you can do. See [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a favour if you want to install non-Apple packages and install a package manager such as `homebrew` which is a matter of copying and pasting a single line from the [homebrew website](http://brew.sh).

Then you can find any packages you want with:

```
brew search httrack
```

and install them and build them with

```
brew install httrack
```

and remove them with

```
brew rm httrack
```

and update all installed packages with

```
brew update && brew upgrade --all && brew cleanup
```

Comment: And how to open it? Its not available in applications.

Comment: It will be in `/usr/local/bin`, so in the Terminal, you would type `/usr/local/bin/httrack` to start it, or preferably, edit your PATH to include `/usr/local/bin`, then you would only need to type `httrack`.

Answer (score 0):

You can install httrack in mac using homebrow package manager.
Follow these steps to run and clone any website using httrack.

1. Open terminal.
2. Type these commands on the Terminal:

   ruby -e “$(curl -fsSL
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" <
   /dev/null 2> /dev/null
3. Type this command

   brew install httrack

httrack will be download in this folder “/usr/local/Cellar/httrack/”

1. After download type this command in terminal

   cd /

   cd /usr/local/Cellar/httrack/3.49.2_1/bin
2. Type `httrack` and hit enter (it will open httrack app in terminal)
3. Enter your project name and click enter
4. Enter the Base path you want to save the files to and click
5. enter Enter the website url you want to clone and click
6. enter Type the number related to “Mirror web site(s) and fill all options
7. Type “Y” for Ready to launch the mirror? and click enter

Answer (score 0):

@jww [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34329479/3585796) helped me to understand the problem, but instead of downloading it manually, you can use **brew** version of **openssl**.

1. Install it:

   ```
   brew install openssl@1.1
   ```
2. Run `brew info openssl@1.1`, you should see something like this:

   ```
   $ brew info openssl@1.1

   ...
   For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
     export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
     export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
   ...
   ```
3. You need these two `export` lines with `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` - path may be different depending on Intel/ARM based processor. Run them before `configure`:

   ```
   export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr && make -j8 && make install
   ```